# Fields Initilizers (Static or not) and Constructor (Static or not) which one runs first

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, constructor, initializer

Something is not clear to me, according to what I read:

1. `Field Initializers` run before Constructors.
2. `Static` `field Initializers` execute before the `static` `constructor` is called (which is still compatible with point 1.).
3. If a type has no static constructor, `field Initializers` will execute before the type being used (as I understand : not being instantiated but rather being used)

This example explains :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.X);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
    public static int X = 3;

    Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In constructor: " + X);
    }
}
```

This Code Prints 0, then 3 ! How could that be possible? When we use Foo by doing Foo.X the two first initializers are called, before the constructor (that's ok so far), when

```
public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
```

is executed it should run its own 2 initializers before calling the constructor (Point 1) whereas it runs the constructor first and prints X with 0 as a default value.

I can't really follow the logic on this, please clarify to me.

Edit : what I expect to happen :

1. when Foo.X : execute: public static Foo Instance = new Foo();
2. before calling the constructor that prints ("In constructor: " + X), public static int X = 3; should be executed, but it happens that  the constructor fires first, isn't supposed that the fields complete running first ? I mean even when jumping inside creating a new Foo instance fields must be run first.
3. From the two last points I expect to print 3 then 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If a type has no static constructor, field Initializers will execute before the type being used (as I understand : not being instantiated but rather being used)

Not necessarily.

If there is no static constructor, then *static field initializers* will be executed at some time before a static field is first used - but the static field initializers *don't* have to execute before any instances are created.

From the C# 5 specification section 10.5.5.1:

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. If a static constructor (§10.12) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

But in your case, you're just seeing that when the constructor of `Foo` is called in order to initialize `Instance`, `X` is still 0, because it hasn't been assigned a value. The field initializers are executed in textual order, so `Instance` is assigned a value before `X`. It's as simple as that - it's not a matter of timing between static fields and instance fields, as you haven't *got* any instance fields.

EDIT: It seems that you're being getting confused by the constructor call. `Foo` is already being initialized - the constructor call doesn't change that, and there's no "second initialization". The constructor is called normally, prints "0" and then returns. *Then* `X` is assigned a value of 3.

Comment: I know that The field initializers are executed in textual order, so Instance is assigned a value before X, the problem is that when it is assigned a value (means the constructor is called) hence it's done before assigning 3 into X, how could that be possible (Point 1.)

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: It doesn't - it prints 0. You only print 3 when you print `Foo.X` *after* all the static initializers have executed. #To make it clearer, change your code in the constructor to: `Console.WriteLine("In constructor: " + X);`. It's not really clear what you expect to happen, but when you call the constructor of `Foo` *within the `Foo` type initializer* the type initializer is already running, so it isn't run again separately.

Comment: I'm sorry if I may be slow catching this, I updated the question to explain what I expect

Comment: @AymenDaoudi: You've said that you expect `X = 3` to be executed before the constructor executes, but not *why*. The assignment to `Instance` can't complete until the constructor completes, and that happens *before* the assignment of `X = 3`. Note that both fields here are static fields - all you're seeing is the side-effect of a static field initializer calling a constructor, thus allowing the default value of another static field to be seen.

Comment: Thx Jon so much I get it now

Answer (score 0):

`Foo()` constructor is not a static constructor, hence its not run first as in with your `case 3`.

Hence, the fields are first initialized from top to bottom.

When `static Foo` is first initialized, it is executed and that is what prints `0`, then when `X` is initialized, that's what is printed with `System.Console.WriteLine()` call.

Comment: The problem is that when, calling Foo.X it does Top to Bottom, when proceding Top to Bottom it encounters public static Foo Instance = new Foo(); it runs bottom to up if it's not it would never print 0 , may be me I'm not really catching it

Comment: Its going top to bottom, `static Foo Instance` being initialized calls the constructor, and remember, until `static int X` hasn't been encountered, `X` is still `0`. Then after initializing of `Instance` it also assigns the value of `X` to `3`. That is then printed to the console. @AymenDaoudi